# How do I use strcmp with void pointers

Tags: c

I'm trying to solve the following question: Write code that checks if an array of ints or c-strings contains two identical items next to each other using void pointers. The method that compares integers works but the code for c-strings crashes. I couldn't find anything that indicates what the problem is. Sorry if there's any mistakes this is translated from Dutch.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int array_contains_sequential_doubles(const void* t, int length, int size, int (*compare)(const void* a, const void* b))
{
    const char* p = (const char*)t;
    int i = 1;
    p += size;
    while (i < length) {
        if (compare(p - size, p))
            return 1;
        i++;
        p += size;
    }
    return 0;
}

int compare_int(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    int ia = *((const int*)a);
    int ib = *((const int*)b);
    //printf("%d en %d\n", ia, ib);
    return ia == ib;
}

int compare_string(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    const char** sa = (const char**)a;
    const char** sb = (const char**)b;
    return strcmp(*sa, *sb) == 0;
}

int main()
{
    int numbers_ja[] = { 3, 2, 1 };
    int numbers_neen[] = { 1, 2, 2, 1 };
    char* woorden_ja[] = { "this", "is", "is", "a", "test" };
    char* woorden_neen[] = { "this", "is", "fine" };

    int i = array_contains_sequential_doubles(numbers_ja, sizeof(numbers_ja) / sizeof(int), sizeof(int), compare_int);
    printf("%d\n", i);

    i = array_contains_sequential_doubles(numbers_neen, sizeof(numbers_neen) / sizeof(int), sizeof(int), compare_int);
    printf("%d\n", i);

    i = array_contains_sequential_doubles(numbers_ja, sizeof(woorden_ja) / sizeof(const char*), sizeof(const char*), compare_string);
    printf("%d\n", i);

    i = array_contains_sequential_doubles(numbers_neen, sizeof(woorden_neen) / sizeof(const char*), sizeof(const char*), compare_string);
    printf("%d\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you calling your function with the right arguments?? check when you call `array_contains_sequential_doubles` with `numbers_ja` as the first argument and `sizeof(woorden_ja)` as the second.

Comment: @warte Kop There are typos in the calls of the function for arrays of strings.

Comment: sorry this is translated from dutch, should I edit the question or post again with the dutch code?

Comment: `strcmp()` does not simply look for a different byte in the strings.   It ASSUMES both arguments are arrays with a terminating nul (character with value `'\0'`) and stops only when it encounters that nul in one of the strings - which, practically, means it keeps going through memory in the hope of finding a nul.  If no nul is present, the behaviour is undefined.    Since your code forces the compiler to treat `doubles` AS IF they are a string, and there may be no nul in either value being compared, the behaviour of your code is undefined (among other reasons).

Comment: why would it treat them as doubles though?

Comment: It doesn't.   Your code is using type conversions (aka casts) and implicit conversion involving `void` pointers to FORCE treatment of `doubles` as if they are an array of `char` when `compare_string()` is eventually called - despite the fact they are not.

Comment: I edited the code because I translated something wrong. I think you're talking about the old version is that possible? Do I leave it in or should I ask a new question to get rid of the error?

Comment: I compiled/linked/ran the posted code.  The output was `0 1 1 0` which seems to be correct.  So what is the problem?

Comment: You are correct, I went back to the original code and the error was there in Dutch. I can't believe I've been stuck on this for 5 hours checking and rewriting every other character in my program without spotting this. I edited the question again to the original. I guess I should step back more when checking my code. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't this been written as **woorden** instead of **numbers** ?

```
i = array_contains_sequential_doubles(woorden_ja, sizeof(woorden_ja) / sizeof(const char*), sizeof(const char*), compare_string);
printf("%d\n", i);

i = array_contains_sequential_doubles(woorden_neen, sizeof(woorden_neen) / sizeof(const char*), sizeof(const char*), compare_string);
```